# Is there a way to always view trade route paths?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Trade Routes in Brave New World show up as a border-colored path when you're first establishing them, but after you pick the destination and the caravans start to shuffle along their merry way, they vanish.

Is there some way to always view active trade routes? I'm hoping that there's something similar to how they were demoed in the Trade Route preview.

Comment: Click on the trade routes in the top bar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can see the trade routes by enabling the Trade Routes option in the map options, the same place you enable Resource Icons, Yield Icons, and the Hex Grid. Screenshot below shows a trade route leading north-northwest out of Salvador. Because I'm playing Brazil the line is green and it's hard to see it on the map, but you can see it best underneath the red Austrian scout unit at left. The little arrows are animated. The routes are also visible on the strategic overview map.

[image: Screenshot of trade routes in Brave New World]

In addition you can also see trade routes by hovering the mouse over a trade unit. I've only seen this when looking at another civilization's ship, I'm not clear if you can get this type of display for your own trade route units. This one looks to be the same graphical effect as the video you posted.

[image: Screenshot of ship trade route in Brave New World]